# SQL - Sum and Group By returning incorrect sums

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

So I have the query below which I believe should be working correctly but is returning false values

```
SELECT 
    Period,
    Sum(Amount) as amount

FROM (
    SELECT
        Period,
        Sum(Amount) Amount
    FROM (
        SELECT a.Period, a.Account, SUM(a.Amount) amount
        FROM LedgerAP a
        WHERE a.Period >= @custPeriodStart AND a.Period <= @custPeriodEnd
        GROUP BY a.Period, a.Account

        UNION
        SELECT b.Period, b.Account, SUM(b.Amount) amount
        FROM LedgerAR b
        WHERE b.Period >= @custPeriodStart AND b.Period <= @custPeriodEnd
        GROUP BY b.Period, b.Account

        UNION
        SELECT c.Period, c.Account, SUM(c.Amount) amount
        FROM LedgerEx c
        WHERE c.Period >= @custPeriodStart AND c.Period <= @custPeriodEnd
        GROUP BY c.Period, c.Account

        UNION
        SELECT d.Period, d.Account, SUM(d.Amount) amount
        FROM LedgerMisc d
        WHERE d.Period >= @custPeriodStart AND d.Period <= @custPeriodEnd
        GROUP BY d.Period, d.Account
    ) src1
    GROUP BY Period, Account
) src2

Group by Period
```

What I'm getting is:

```
Period  |  Amount
201501  |  -450.00
201502  |  00
201503  |  00
...     |  ...
201512  |  xxxxxx
```

What I'm expecting is:

```
Period  |  Amount
201501  |  1731262
201502  |  774221
201503  |  770845
...     |  ...
201512  |  xxxxxx
```

In other words SUM() isn't returning the correct values. I know my subquery is correctly returning the values I'm looking for but when I GROUP and SUM the values become very incorrect. I'm dealing with positive and negative amounts but my understanding is SUM() should still work correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: This is probably not the whole problem, but I think you should be using `UNION ALL`. As written, if more than one subquery returns the same amount for the same period and account, only one of them will be included in the set returned from the unions.

Comment: I doubt that would ever happen based on the numbers but thanks I'll make that change wasn't aware of that side effect, still doesn't fix the issue at hand though.

Comment: Are you wanting to sum the absolute values? You don't appear to need to do the grouping in two stages. Why did you do it that way?

Comment: Or maybe I have that backward. Do you need to apply a negative sign to a couple of those table amounts, perhaps to differentiate debits and credits?

Answer (score 0):

in your inner SQL there is a GROUP by Period, Account althoug you are not summing up by period + account but only by period. Please try removinge the acccount in the GROUP BY

```
SELECT
    Period,
    Sum(amount1) Amount
FROM (
    SELECT a.Period, a.Account, SUM(a.Amount) amount1
    FROM LedgerAP a
    WHERE a.Period >= @custPeriodStart AND a.Period <= @custPeriodEnd
    GROUP BY a.Period, a.Account

    UNION
    SELECT b.Period, b.Account, SUM(b.Amount) amount1
    FROM LedgerAR b
    WHERE b.Period >= @custPeriodStart AND b.Period <= @custPeriodEnd
    GROUP BY b.Period, b.Account

    UNION
    SELECT c.Period, c.Account, SUM(c.Amount) amount1
    FROM LedgerEx c
    WHERE c.Period >= @custPeriodStart AND c.Period <= @custPeriodEnd
    GROUP BY c.Period, c.Account

    UNION
    SELECT d.Period, d.Account, SUM(d.Amount) amount1
    FROM LedgerMisc d
    WHERE d.Period >= @custPeriodStart AND d.Period <= @custPeriodEnd
    GROUP BY d.Period, d.Account
) src1
GROUP BY Period
```

Comment: Doesn't fix it, not to mention I need that group by account otherwise the sub query isn't serving its purpose

Comment: OK, but then you need to add in the corresponding SELECT the Account too. Answer edited

Comment: Why? I have tested the sub query how its written functions exactly how I'm expecting it to.

Comment: is your SQL case sensitive? Then please check the spelling of Amount and amount.

Comment: It's not case sensitive, I'm not getting an error the query returns fine, just with the wrong values. sum() isn't actually summing the amounts I'm not sure what it actually is doing.

Comment: Returns the same thing as my above example

Comment: last try :-) I replaced amount by amount1, because amount is being used in the inner SQL and outer SQL. Could maybe confusing. Therefore renamed the selected amount in the inner SQL into amount1 and use amount1 also in the outer SQL